# JQuery-mobile pop up/ dialog box?

Tags: html, dialog, popup, jquery-mobile

I am building an app for mobiles, using jquery mobile framework. I want to be able to make a simple dialog box/pop up, so that when you click on a picture of a "question mark"  the pop up/ dialog box would appear with a simple message.
I have tried different approaches from http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/dialog-alt.html to so many others. I couldnt get non of them to work. So If you know how to make a simple pop up or a simple dialog box could you please give me an example!

Comment: what doesn't work? post your code, everything should work if you do it as described here http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/#/test/docs/pages/page-dialogs.html

Comment: well, i dont have any codes for pop up / dialog, because I couldnt make it work so I just removed every thing. I did exactly as it says in the link above and also the link you gave me , I also tred so many different ways  but I could nt get them to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to open a dialog in jquery mobile you have to use an attribute `data-rel="dialog"` and the href must point to a URL where your dialog lives:

```
<a href="http://jquerymobile.com/test/docs/pages/dialog-alt.html" data-role="button" data-rel="dialog">Open dialog</a>
```

Here's a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vandalo/w3FMh/12/) so you can see how it works.
Hope it helps.

UPDATE:

It seems there's a problem with jQuery Mobile dialog and some devices. 
There's an [issue](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2190) open in the GitHub repository.
I've found this [plugin](http://dev.jtsage.com/#/jQM-SimpleDialog/) which seems to work really well.

Comment: @Saeed Najafi: I had tested it with a a mozilla plug-in and it worked but - you're right - with iBBDemo2 it doesn't. It's seems there's an issue open: https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mobile/issues/2190

Comment: @Saeed Najafi:I've updated my answer. I've found a cool plugin which seems to work and uses the jQuery-Dialog-way.